# Move Tomcat Root

Tags: tomcat

When I start up tomcat, it starts serving out of localhost:8080/. I would like it to start serving out of localhost:8080/aaa. I dont want to replace the "root" webapp with the "aaa" webapp, I want tomcat to treat "/aaa" like "/" in the sense that before where I could do something like

- localhost:8080/ --> root webapp
- localhost:8080/webapp1 --> webapp1
- etc.

I now want to do something like:

- localhost:8080/aaa ---> root webapp
- localhost:8080/aaa/webapp1 --> webapp1
- etc.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do this with Tomcat only, but this is usually achieved with [Apache mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Comment: If you use `mod_proxy` you also need to replace all occurrences of  paths starting with `/` to paths starting with `/aaa/`.  `mod_proxy_html` does this for HTML links, but unfortunately not for paths in JavaScript.  For JavaScript you need something more flexible such as `mod_substitude`, but than you might also replace slashes that where not supposed to be replaced by `/aaa/`.  The most reliable solution would be if tomcat would allow for setting a URL prefix for context paths.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution **but this is an ugly one and not recommended by Tomcat docs** (i.e. adding Context in server.xml is not recommended). This is okay for you to test out on your current server.

You can set these in your Tomcat `server.xml`.

Add a `<Context>` element within the `<Host>` like below and set the `path` as your `"/aaa"` prefix

This should allow you to access http: //localhost:8080/aaa will directly take you to webapp "root"

```
<Context docBase="rootwebapp" path="/aaa" reloadable="true"  />
```

Add another `Context` with the path to "/aaa/webapp1" like below should allow you to access webapp1 as http: //localhost:8080/aaa/webapp1

```
<Context docBase="webapp1" path="/aaa/webapp1" reloadable="true"  />
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. In addition, it looks like you'd have to explicitly set the path for each web app. What I think we're looking for is to simply set a container-wide default prefix for all context paths (including the root). It doesn't appear to be possible, which really surprises me.